# Datatype to use for primary key with data that will be purged

Tags: sql-server

We will be logging requests and response data and storing to SQL Serve 2008r2.  This data will be purged at a regular interval: e.g. everyday everything 30 days old will be deleted.

What data type should we use for keys in this schema when we know the data will be purged at regular intervals?  A sequential identity would exceed 2^31 if we do not reseed after purging.

We will be querying for the request/response data based on the LogActivity Id in the RequestLog table.

[image]

Comment: use a 64bit int instead? Plus, if it's sequential, why waste HALF of your id space by making it signed? an ID should almost always be an unsigned.

Comment: @MarcB SQL Server does not support unsigned integers.

Comment: Why not just use int and reseed the identity when you purge the old data?

Comment: @SeanLange that was a consideration, but seemed to add complexity where it was not needed.  I think -BaconBits- is correct in that I vastly understimated the scale of BIGINT.

Comment: Not sure how it adds complexity but I don't know the whole project. Would be simple to just truncate the table when clearing out the old data. BIGINT would also be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `BIGINT`.  You will not run out.  Like many people, you're vastly underestimating the scale of a 63 bit number.

If you create 3 billion records every second, it will still take you about 100 years to run out:

```
100 years * 365.25 days/yr * 24 hrs/day * 60 min/hr * 60 sec/min = 3,155,760,000 seconds.
```

Max `BIGINT` is 2^63-1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

```
9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / 3,155,760,000 ~= 2,924,712,087 records per second
```

30 days worth of 8 byte integers generated at that rate:

```
8 bytes * 2924712087 per second * 60 seconds/min * 60 min/hour * 24 hours/day * 30 days/month = 60,646,829,836,032,000
```

Or 60.6 petabytes.  Just for that many 8 byte keys.  If you used `int`, it would still be 30 petabytes.  Just to store the keys.  Are you seriously going to be generating that much data?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (i.e. GUID).  They are basically throw-away values, and are easy to generate using the `NEWID()` function:

```
INSERT INTO [Requests] 
([Id], [Request], [Response], [CreateDateTime]) 
VALUES
(NEWID(), @RequestValue, @ResponseValue, GETDATE())
```

You can also generate the GUID in your code ahead of time.  This has the benefit of allowing you to work with the ID value before you even insert the record into the database (e.g. adding your objects to an identity map, etc.).  You can then perform your inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Requests] 
([Id], [Request], [Response], [CreateDateTime]) 
VALUES
(@ID, @RequestValue, @ResponseValue, GETDATE())
```

Comment: They are also absolutely awful as a clustered index and are a total pita to work with. Given the nature of the original information I would not use a guid here because it is also likely going to be the clustered index.

Comment: @SeanLange -- Okay, a good point.  But GUID is still not a bad choice overall for a PK ([Jeff Atwood agrees](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/)).

Comment: They are fine as a PK but not good as the clustered index. Personally I avoid them unless absolutely necessary because they make debugging so much more painful.

Answer (score -1):

Use CreateDateTime as PK - it will last forever.

Comment: Very bad idea, IMX.  DateTimes aren't as unique as we like to think they are.  Clocks go out of sync (especially in a VM environment), clocks change for daylight saving, time zones change, etc.  You're tying something that's meant solely to identify the uniqueness of your record to something as imprecise as a computer clock and something that's affected by outside factors like what your nation decides the time is.  Unique dates are miserable.